# Docker - Instance method "open" is already defined in Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, spree, dockerfile

I have a SpreeCommerce + rails app which I am looking to deploy to AWS using docker.

The image builds fine but when I run the container it refuses to start. I get the following error:

```
Instance method "open" is already defined in Object, 
use generic helper instead or set 
StateMachines::Machine.ignore_method_conflicts = true.
App 70 stderr:
```

Has anybody had experience with this error before? I am using the finnlabs/rails base image and can post my Dockerfile if this helps!

Thanks!

Comment: This looks more like an error in your application and should not be related to Docker. Make sure that you are properly defining the method "open" (maybe you need to override like in Java).

Comment: Same error in Spree with default setup from scratch.  Anyone know where to "set " this?  I tried in environments and got an error.  All google results I have found point to the source-code where the error is coded - but nothing on how to fix this.

Comment: This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455498/spree-checkout-remove-step is a very helpfull solution, verifyed with spree 3.0.5